# Style input text through wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

**NOTE:Thanks to HamZa the question is answered, but the question is locked.So I'm quoting the answer in the last block of code in the question for fast reference.**

Hello I would like to do something like this in wordpress:

```
 [my_shortcode 'text1', 'text2', ... 'textn'] or something similar
```

Desired Output something like this below:

```
  <span class="myclass">text1</span>
  <span class="myclass">text2</span>
  <span class="myclass">text3</span>
  .....
  .....
  <span class="myclass">textn</span>
```

For as many text items there are in the shortcode. Their ammount will be unknown.

Any ideas please?

EDIT:
So far I know opnly how to do this

```
[my_shortcode]text1,text2....[/my_shortcode]

add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' ); 
function my_shortcode_function($atts, $content ) {
    return '<span class="myclass">'.$content.'</span>';
}
```

but it takes all the text-items as one of course. Somewhere I have to use an array but I don't know how. Is it possible to do it, if I don't know the number of text-items?

**Correct Answer**

```
   add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
   function my_shortcode_function($atts, $content) {
        $content_array = preg_split('~\s*,\s*~', $content);
        $return_array = array();
        foreach($content_array as $arr){
              $return_array[] = '<span class="myclass">'.$arr.'</span>';
        }
        return implode($return_array);
   }
```

Comment: Cool, so where's the problem ?

Comment: I'm not understanding this? Are you pulling this from the DB with wp_query ? If so you need a while loop... Please explain more thanks

Comment: Thank you for your interest guys. The text items are known words which need to be styled. Each time there will be different words. The number of the words is unknown. They are not pulled from anywhere it is custom text which will be used into the shortcode. Two examples:
[my_shortcode 'word1', 'word2'], 
[my_shortcode 'word5', 'word6', 'word7']
at the output each word needs to have the same css class assigned. The problem is that it is going to be my first shortcode and I don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: @drazon try something like [this](http://pastebin.com/17v6yRgp)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH HamZa! That did exactly what I was looking for, I wish I could mark your answer as correct but the question is locked. I'm going to edit the question and mention the answer. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Shortcoder plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcoder/) it gives you an easy interface to create shortcodes

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't help.